# Problems with Promises

Tags: javascript

I am sort of novice to JS and experimenting how the things work. How can I output error in the following case:

```
var k =Promise.resolve(function(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>reject("Error"))
});
k.then(...)
```

Comment: k.catch() will catch the error if there is any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `catch()` block after then.

The `catch()` method returns a `Promise` and deals with rejected cases only. It behaves the same as calling `Promise.prototype.then(undefined, onRejected)`. See here for [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)

```
var k =Promise.resolve(function(){
            return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>reject("Error"))
        });
```

Like this

```
k.then(...).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error)

        })
```